# What's causing my code to infinitely loop?

Tags: php, html

I have this code:

```
<?php 

 include ('php/Database.php');

 $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tblusers");
 $row = $sql->fetch_object();

 if ($sql) {
      while ($row) {
           echo "<h2>$row->first_name</h2>
                 $row->last_name";
          }
 }
?>
```

And it is producing an infinite loop. I'm expecting that it will display all the records from my tblusers.

I expected something like:

```
 **John** 
 Smith
 **Jane** 
 Doe
 **James**
 Bond
```

Instead, it showed:

```
 **John**
 Smith**
 **John**
 Smith
 **John**
 Smith
 **John**
 Smith
 **John**
 Smith
 **John**
 Smith
 **John**
 Smith
 **John**
 Smith
```

infinitely....

What's wrong with this? I'm a total newbie btw, if you haven't already deduced from my question..

Answer (score 2):

It should be `while($row = $sql->fetch_object())`.

Comment: Well... this is a little embarassing. Thank you, btw! But why didn't my previous code work tho? I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: @LeonardCupat: The function `$sql->fetch_object()` retrieves one result at a time, and becomes false once it runs out of results to retrieve. If you only execute it once, outside the loop, it will always be true (and contain the first information retrieved); therefore, you must execute it until it becomes false.